# How to add the frameworks libsqlite.dylib to the gcc_flags arguments in MonoTouch?

Tags: binding, xamarin.ios

I have an Objective C static library that I am trying to import into MonoTouch and building it into (Monotouch.XGPush.dll). the original library name is:libXG-SDK.a).

The problem that I am encountering, though, is that the library depends on libsqlite.dylib and the following framework ,and I do not know how to include these frameworks in my MonoTouch application.

libsqlite.dylib 
CFNetwork.framework , SystemConfiguration.framework , CoreTelephony.framework , libz.dylib , libXG-SDK.a

linker error log:

error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _sqlite3_bind_int64. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.

error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _sqlite3_bind_text. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.

error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _sqlite3_clear_bindings. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.

error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _sqlite3_step. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.

error MT5202: Native linking failed. Please review the build log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add args: LinkerFlags = "-lz -lsqlite3.0", that's ok.